# How to compare and use only time from datetime format in sql? My insertion is given in datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql

Please note that this is not my full code for the query. I just need to understand how to compare the time only.
Here is my table creation code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ActivityBooking` (
  `ActivityTime` datetime  NOT NULL,
  `NumPeople` INT NULL,
  `ActivityID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `GuideID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Reservation_ReservationID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ActivityTime`, `ActivityID`),
  INDEX `fk_ActivityBooking_Activity1_idx` (`ActivityID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ActivityBooking_Staff1_idx` (`GuideID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ActivityBooking_Reservation1_idx` (`Reservation_ReservationID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ActivityBooking_Activity1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ActivityID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Activity` (`ActivityID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ActivityBooking_Staff1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`GuideID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Staff` (`StaffID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ActivityBooking_Reservation1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Reservation_ReservationID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Reservation` (`ReservationID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Table insertion

```
Insert into activitybooking values('2020-10-7 15:17:00',6,'C01','S5','R321');
Insert into activitybooking values('2020-12-8 16:15:00',7,'D01','S2','R321');
Insert into activitybooking values('2020-11-9 18:12:00',2,'E01','R321','S4');
```

Currently I am stuck because I want to display results for bookings made after mid-day and before 4pm. But I don't know how to just compare the time from the datetime format. I am not adding the codes for the other tables in order to keep the information here minimum. But if needed I can provide.

```
select customerfname, customerlname, activityname
from customer, activitybooking,activity
where activity.activityid = activitybooking.activityid
and activitytime between time('12-0-0') and time('16-0-0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is apply the `TIME` function to your `activitytime` column and then compare it to `12:00:00` and `16:00:00`:

```
TIME(activitytime) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
```

Note if you don't want to include `16:00:00` replace that with `15:59:59`. Also, if you write the time strings in `HH:mm:ss` format then you don't need to apply `TIME` to them and can just compare directly.